# Keeping/inserting leading 0's

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to get and keep leading 0's in my project. Here are the currently relevant pieces of code:

```
Dim jobNum As String

 jobNum = Left(r1.Cells(1, 1), 6)

 r2.Cells(1, JOBCOL) = (jobNum)
 r2.Cells(1, JOBCOL).NumberFormat = "@"
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Stuff I've tried -

```
 r2.Cells(1, JOBCOL) = CStr(jobNum)
```

- trying to keep it in string mode, because maybe it's pasting it that's the issue?

```
 If Len(jobNum) = 4 Then
  jobNum = "'00" & jobNum
  Else
  jobNum = jobNum
  End If
```

Ok, ok, if I can't get it to read it properly, maybe I can manually add it in? (expected length is 6, if the length registers as 4 I have an issue, and I need to add in two leading 0's)

And finally, my attempt to get it to read properly in the first place:

```
Dim Jobnum as String
Dim Jobnumfixed as Integer

jobNum = Left(r1.Cells(1, 1), 6)
jobnumfixed = format (jobnum, "000000")
```

I took all of these from [Excel VBA Won't Keep Leading Zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686732/excel-vba-wont-keep-leading-zeroes) . However, none of them have ended up with the expected result, which is to get and keep some leading 0's in my sheet. What am I doing wrong? Where should I be looking to fix this?

Thank you

Edit: Managed to get it to work.    jobNum = Left(r1.Cells(1, 1), 6) became  jobNum = ("'" & Left(r1.Cells(1, 1), 6)), and it all works now. Hurray!

Comment: Format the cell as text in order to keep the leading zeros

Comment: Do you need the jobnum to be a number or text? If text, take @Sorceri's suggestion of formatting the cells as text before entering the data. If numbers, simply use custom formatting with "000000" to display each number padded to 6 digits with leading zeroes (4 becomes 000004 and 123 becomes 000123).

Comment: ...and when I say "custom formatting", I don't mean the `Format` function, but instead the format dropdown on the "Home" tab in the ribbon.

Comment: added the line  r2.Cells(1, JOBCOL).NumberFormat = "@" - still not getting there. Ditto with going to the home tab and changing the default format. Edit: I got it working! I added in ("'"&...) to the start of my jobnum=, and it all works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to place leading zeros into a **number**:

```
Sub LeadingZerosNumbers()
    Dim N As Long

    N = 1137

    Range("A1").Value = N
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "000000"
End Sub
```

and here is a way to place leading zeros into **text** that looks like a number:

```
Sub LeadingZerosText()
    Dim N As Long

    N = 1137

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Value = "00" & N

End Sub
```

In both cases **A1** will display:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!   jobNum = ("'" & Left(r1.Cells(1, 1), 6)) managed to get it to work